# How to count the lines which contain a specific range or interval of numbers using awk or grep?

Tags: awk, grep

I have these lines:

```
DL_SINR 48 106.202 660.04 16.9651 18 7992
DL_SINR 49 116.333 660.363 16.9413 18 7992
DL_SINR 50 135.815 654.794 24.218 24 13536
```

I want to count which lines contain a number between `100.0` and `105.0` in the third column.

I've searched a lot, but I couldn't find it. It will be great with grep or awk.

Answer (score 3):

`Awk` is a good tool for the job. It splits line in spaces and they are numbered beginning with `1`, so third field will be `$3`.

```
awk '$3 >= 100.0 && $3 <= 105.0 { count++ } END { print count ? count : 0 }' infile
```

Comment: You are forgetting `BEGIN`... ?

Comment: This has been the fastest and perfect answer that I've had. You are a genius, Thanks a lot, seriusly you have saved me.

Comment: @twalberg : Somehow result is zero without `BEGIN` and 3 with it.

Comment: @iamauser Well, given only the sample input, the result *should* be zero, as `$3 > 105` for all three lines.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `awk` to get the lines with 3rd column value ranging between 100 and 105 and use `wc -l` to get the total number of lines.

```
awk '$3>=100&&$3<=105 {print $0}'  test.txt | wc -l
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) :

```
$ perl -anE '$c++ if ($F[2] >= 100.0 and $F[2] <= 150.0);END{say $c}' file
3
```

Comment: The `-l` switch is not needed. It handles end of lines in input and output but you don't use them.

Comment: True, removed in my post